# Can I use Video.JS as an audio player?

Tags: video.js

Can I use Video JS as an audio player if I did the following:

- changed the `<video>` tags to `<audio>`
- Removed the video area (where the video is shown)

Would more than that be required? I love the player and would like a matched style as the rest of my website (with the websites video players that use VideoJS).

Comment: "Changed the tags to"... what?

Comment: Stack overflow didn't like the raw HTML, updated the post with code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VideoJS currently does not support `audio`, but there is an open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/537).

In the meantime you could have a look at [videojs-playlist](http://tim-peterson.github.io/videojs-playlist/), which is a plugin for Video.js

Answer (score 29):

VideoJS has rolled out an update to support audio playback.

[Video.js 4.9 - Now audio can join the party!](http://blog.videojs.com/post/99014232526/videojs-49-now-audio-can-join-the-party)